# Apex Test Class Assert for Void?

Tags: apex, trigger, future, httprequest

How can I build an Apex test class to validate a class method that has a `@future` HTTPRequest setting? The `@future` method returns a void, but I can't test a void value with a `System.assert[Not]Equals`...

The change to the system that triggers the future async call happens on user interaction, so any changes to the system would already be set. The scenario is that the user changes an sObject field (Account Owner) and that change triggers the async http request:

```
trigger AccountOwnerUpdate on Account (after update) {
    for (Account a : Trigger.new){
        if (a.OwnerId != Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).OwnerId) {
            List<Account> aId = [Select OwnerId From Account where Id = :a.Id];
            List<User> oName = [Select Name from User where Id = :aId[0].OwnerId];

            String newOwnerName = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(oName[0].Name, 'UTF-8');
            String accountId = a.Id;

            AccountOwnerUpdateTest.remoteUpdateAccountOwner(accountId, newOwnerName);
        }
    }
}


global class AccountOwnerUpdateTest {
     @future(callout = true)
     public static void remoteUpdateAccountOwner(String accountId, String newOwnerName) {

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        String endpoint = '[My url]/'+accountId+'/[param]/'+newOwnerName;

        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod('GET');

        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

   }
}

@isTest (seeAllData=true)
public class AccountOwnerUpdateTestClass {
    static testMethod void validateOwnerUpdate() {
        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpRequestResponseGenerator());
        AccountOwnerUpdateTest.remoteUpdateAccountOwner('id','owner');
        Test.stopTest();
// System.assertEquals([?])
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing up several ideas here. Assertions do not provide code coverage, but rather, guarantee the functionality works as expected. Also, you can re-query the data to assert on the outcome. It will be much easier to provide guidance if you **[edit]** your post to include what code you are trying to test, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Have you looked at [Testing HTTP Callouts by Implementing the HttpCalloutMock Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm)? It gives some pretty good guidance that applies to your situation here.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - yes, but that test is not looking for a void response from the MockHttpRequest

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is one where a future method is called that does a callout.

**How do you assert that this happened?**

Immediately before `AccountOwnerUpdateTest.remoteUpdateAccountOwner('id','owner');` do: `Integer calloutsBefore = Limits.getCallouts();`

After `Test.stopTest()` (as the async executuon won't occur until this statement is reached)

```
System.assertEquals(calloutsBefore+batchsizebeingtested,Limits.getCallouts());
```

**How do you assert the callout worked?**

This is more problematic because you have to mock the results so you really can't test the actual remote Http service did what you expect. hence, to address this would be done via integration testing using live users, or Selenium-type tools.

Comment: Shouldn't all your `Limits` calls come between `startTest()` and `stopTest()`? Specifically, don't you want to do one between the `@future` execution and `stopTest` to verify a callout was made?

Comment: @adrianlarson oops - right.  edited answer; since future doesn't run until  `Test.stopTest())` the assert has to happen there.  Of course, if multiple callouts (multimock), the assertion is more complex

Comment: Hmm...I guess you can't really ever test that a callout was fired made then, I forgot about that. You'd have to assert against the mock then, right?

Comment: @adrianlarson one could, i suppose, pass an object known to the testmethod to the mock callout constructor and have the `respond` method update the object and then the testmethod can assert that the mock was actually invoked

Comment: thanks @cropredy @AdrianLarson - I've added the `Limits` into the test, but the assertion is still failing unless I remove `batchsizebeingtested` - with that removed, the test passes, but I still have no code coverage.

Comment: @NathanBennett - your testmethod : `AccountOwnerUpdateTest.remoteUpdateAccountOwner('id','owner');` only tests the future method, since your test method isn't inserting any accounts, no trigger is fired so the trigger class isn't covered

Comment: Thx @cropredy - do you mean to say that within the test class I should update the ownerId on the Account programmatically, and then detect if the trigger fired the request? (ie use the test class to test the user action, not just the firing of the http request)

Comment: @nathanBennett well, if you need to verify the trigger, you need, in the testmethod, to mock an Account and then update it. If all you need to do is verify the future method, then your test method is doing all it needs to